# Finding the 99th derivative of $\sin (x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find ${\frac{d^{99}}{dx^{99}}(\sin (x))}$.
>   What should I do after this?
>   ${\frac{d}{dx}(\sin (x))=\cos (x)}$

Comment: You should differentiate $98$ more times.

Comment: You should notice that there is a cycle in the derivatives so you won't have to do $98$ more steps.  MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the proper font and spacing, so \sin x gives $\sin x$ as opposed to sin x which gives $sin x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may prove that
$$
\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}(\sin x)=\sin\left(x+n\frac \pi2 \right)
$$ giving
$$
\frac{d^{99}}{dx^{99}}(\sin x)=\sin\left(x+\frac{99\pi}2 \right)=\sin\left(x+48 \pi+\frac{3\pi}2 \right)=-\cos x.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \sin x = -\sin x$

$\frac{d^4}{dx^4} \sin x = \sin x$

So you notice that taking the 96'th derivative will be $\sin x$ again. That is because doing the 96'th derivative is the same as doing 4th derivative 24 times and doing the 4th derivative didn't do anything. Now you just have to do 3 more to get 99 from 96.

Answer (score 0):

After differentiating 4 times the result will be sinx again. So after differentiating any multiple of 4 times will give sinx again . 99÷4 yields remainder 3 so the answer will be -cosx ie it is the same as differentiating sinx 3 times